# Inbuild Pipeline arguments

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I wanted to know how to get list of in-built pipeline arguments in Data Fusion Pipeline ?

I am not able to find them anywhere on the documentation as well as on the internet.

Comment: What do you mean with in-built arguments? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Built-in arguments which are already there with the pipeline by default like one in know 'logicalStartTime'.

Comment: logicalStartTime is the only argument added by the system. Even for that, I would recommend using the macro (https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/6.2.1/en/developer-manual/pipelines/creating-pipelines.html#H4916) instead of accessing it directly, as it has additional features for formatting the time or doing simple math on it.

Comment: @SUDHIRGARG does Albert comment answers your question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Albert, That answers my question

Answer (score 1):

As discussed, `logicalStartTime` is the only argument added by the system.

To get some parameter even those added by the system its recommended using [macros](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/6.2.1/en/developer-manual/pipelines/creating-pipelines.html#H2140) that allow placeholders for properties that are unknown at configure time but are known and provided at runtime. For logicalStartTime we have the pre-defined macro named **Logical Start Time Function** that can be used like below:

```
${logicalStartTime([timeFormat[,offset [,timezone])}
```

Where:

- **timeFormat**: Time format string, in the format of a Java SimpleDateFormat
- **offset**: An offset of time before the actual logical start time
- **timezone**: Timezone to be used for the logical start time

The documentations shows us an example:

> For example, suppose the logical start time of a pipeline run is
> 2016-01-01T00:00:00 and this macro is provided:
>
> ${logicalStartTime(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss,1d-4h+30m)}
>
> The format is
> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss and the offset is 1d-4h+30m before the logical
> start time. This means the macro will be replaced with
> 2015-12-31T03:30:00, since the offset translates to 20.5 hours. The
> entire macro evaluates to 20.5 hours before midnight of January 1,
> 2016.